# How to reduce the cost of Sql query?

Tags: sql

I want to reduce the cost of below query, could anyone provide the hint or index to use?

```
SELECT HCA2.Cust_account_id HCA1ACCOUNT, OS.LEGAL_ENTITY_ID AS HCA1LEID, 
        OBL.AMOUNT AS UNBILLED_AMOUNT1 
FROM  HZ_CUST_ACCOUNTS HCA2,
      OSS_SUBSCRIPTIONS OS,
      OSS_BILL_LINES OBL, 
      OSS_PRODUCTS OP   
WHERE HCA2.CUST_ACCOUNT_ID = OS.BILL_TO_ACCT_ID 
  AND OS.SUBSCRIPTION_ID =OBL.SUBSCRIPTION_ID
  AND OBL.SUBSCRIPTION_PRODUCT_ID=OP.SUBSCRIPTION_PRODUCT_ID 
  AND OS.SUBSCRIPTION_ID=OP.SUBSCRIPTION_ID 
  AND NVL(OBL.AR_INTERFACE_YN,'N')='N' 
  AND OBL.VERSION_TYPE='C'
  AND OP.VERSION_TYPE='C'
```

Showing the below cost.

```
| Id  | Operation                    | Name                | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT             |                     |     7 |   679 |  5330   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  NESTED LOOPS                |                     |     7 |   679 |  5330   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|*  2 |   HASH JOIN                  |                     |     7 |   609 |  5330   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|*  3 |    HASH JOIN                 |                     | 31143 |  1581K|  2220   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|   4 |     TABLE ACCESS STORAGE FULL| oss_subscriptions   |  7460 |   218K|   512   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|*  5 |     TABLE ACCESS STORAGE FULL| oss_products        | 31143 |   669K|  1708   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|*  6 |    TABLE ACCESS STORAGE FULL | oss_bill_lines      | 53670 |  1834K|  3110   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|*  7 |   INDEX UNIQUE SCAN          | HZ_CUST_ACCOUNTS_PK |     1 |    10 |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |
```

I tried the index and hint partition etc.. but not working.

Comment: why are you using old style joins?

Comment: [Why should I "tag my RDBMS"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms) - please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: Well, do you have indexes on the columns you are referencing in the WHERE clause?  What indexes did you add?  How large are these tables?

Comment: Please read [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/271055/1115360).

Comment: SUBSCRIPTION_PRODUCT_ID of both table

Comment: one thing you could try in the absence of the above requested info... replace the NVL function with (`OBL.AR_INTERFACE_YN = 'N' OR OBL.AR_INTERFACE_YN IS NULL`). Putting functions in a filter can hinder performance, although I am referring specifically to SQL Server (see @marc_s comment), not sure if that is the case with other RDBMS

Comment: @SamCohen-Devries -- NVL is like COALESCE -- DB platforms are optimized for the operation and it will be faster than the code you posted on most (all major) systems.

Comment: @SamCohen-Devries It's Oracle, as per my understanding indexes does not work if we uses the OR keyword.

Comment: @Askquestion -- or keyword has nothing to do with indexes

Answer (score 0):

Here is your code re-written with modern joins and using left joins.

It is very likely this will speed up the code significantly -- with left joins and not full joins the server needs to do less work.
Also notice the last line -- if you look at the logic of the other joins that is probably not needed unless your DB has a very strange structure.

```
SELECT HCA2.Cust_account_id HCA1ACCOUNT, OS.LEGAL_ENTITY_ID AS HCA1LEID, 
        OBL.AMOUNT AS UNBILLED_AMOUNT1 
FROM  HZ_CUST_ACCOUNTS HCA2
LEFT JOIN OSS_SUBSCRIPTIONS OS ON HCA2.CUST_ACCOUNT_ID = OS.BILL_TO_ACCT_ID
LEFT JOIN OSS_BILL_LINES OBL ON OS.SUBSCRIPTION_ID = OBL.SUBSCRIPTION_ID
                            AND NVL(OBL.AR_INTERFACE_YN,'N')='N'
                            AND OBL.VERSION_TYPE='C'
LEFT JOIN OSS_PRODUCTS OP ON OBL.SUBSCRIPTION_PRODUCT_ID = OP.SUBSCRIPTION_PRODUCT_ID 
                         AND OP.VERSION_TYPE='C'
                         AND OS.SUBSCRIPTION_ID = OP.SUBSCRIPTION_ID -- should not be needed
```

Your code (as written) is using a cross join with all tables, which is much slower than a join or a left join.  Please try the code above.  If you still see performance issues then you need to add indexes for the columns that are being joined.

Comment: Still cost is same not reduced.

Comment: @Askquestion -- did it run faster?

Comment: Cost is same as previous.

Comment: @Askquestion -- the cost shown is not always the result of running the query - it depends on the platform.   Did you try running both queries?

Comment: Apologies for late reply,  increase the data, also not working fast.